# Intercept calls to HTML5 canvas element

Tags: javascript

I have a WEB application, that renders it's entire User Interface in an HTML5 canvas.
Note that I can't change the current application.

Currently, this application is being tested using Selenium.
This is done by simulating a click event at a given location in the browser window.
After the click has been executed, a sleep of 2 seconds is being performed to ensure that the entire UI is ready before moving to the next step.

Due to all the 'wait' statements, testing the application is very slow.

Therefore, I thought it was an idea to intercept all calls to the HTML5 canvas.
That way I can rely on the triggered events to know if the UI is ready to move to the next step.

Assume that I have the following code in my application that renders the canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasElement");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

Is there a way to intercept the 'fillRect' event?
I tought something along the lines:

```
var canvasProxy = document.getElementById("canvasElement");

canvasProxy.addEventListener("getContext", function(event) {
  console.log("Hello");
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasElement");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

Unforuntately this is not working.

I've created a JSFiddle to play with the example.
https://jsfiddle.net/5cknym74/4/

Amy toughts?

Comment: Does the real code have any asynchronous code? Things like HTTP requests, ...? Or is all synchronous?

Comment: Some HTTP requests are being done, but I think they are out of the question. Why is that important?

Comment: If it would be completely synchronous, setting a very short timeout on the page would be a solution.

Comment: For some cases it indeed night be a solution, but currently I'm looking for a solution in JS in how to intercept canvas drawings. If I have a JS method that does some complex calculations before updating the UI, I want to intercept the call that draws the result so that my script is able to continue immediately.

Comment: There is nothing like that in the DOM interface.

Answer (score 2):

I played a bit around with the JS API and it seems that the following might be working:

```
// SECTION: Store a reference to all the HTML5 'canvas' element methods.
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._captureStream              = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.captureStream;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._getContext                 = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._toDataURL                  = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._toBlob                     = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._transferControlToOffscreen = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.transferControlToOffscreen;
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype._mozGetAsFile               = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.mozGetAsFile;

// SECTION: Patch the HTML5 'canvas' element methods.
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.captureStream = function(frameRate) {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.captureStream');

    return this._captureStream(frameRate);
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function(contextType, contextAttributes) {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext');
    console.log('PROPERTIES:');
    console.log('  contextType: ' + contextType);

    return this._getContext(contextType, contextAttributes);
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function(type, encoderOptions) {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL');

    return this._toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob = function(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument) {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob');

    return this._toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument);
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.transferControlToOffscreen = function() {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.transferControlToOffscreen');

    return this._transferControlToOffscreen();
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.mozGetAsFile = function(name, type) {
    console.log('INTERCEPTING: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.mozGetAsFile');

    return this._mozGetAsFile(name, type);
}
```

Now that I can intercept the calls, I can find out which calls are responsible that draw a button and react accordingly.